# Running a subset of tests in Gradle

Tags: java, scala, junit, gradle

I have a multiproject gradle build which contains a mix of Java with JUnit and Scala with Specs tests, plus a few other technologies.

I have pretty much everything building fine but I am hitting an issue with the tests.

My projects are all organised with the following structure

```
<project>/src/main/... - containing the production source code
<project>/src/tests-unit/... - containing the JUnit or Specs test code
```

and then optionally a combination of

```
<project>/src/tests-util/... - containing utility classes for setting up tests
<project>/src/tests-functional/... - containing functional level test code
<project>/src/tests-integration/... - containing integration level test code
```

My problem is that running grade tests on this project will actually run the tests in all the test directories and I want to be able to control what tests are being run. I had the idea of setting up a separate task for each level of test, but how do I specify to just run tests in the **/src/tests-unit** hierarchy and ignore the others?

I have tried several things including setting the runtimeClasspath of the sourceset for a target but I just get a deprecation warning for this and it has no effect.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd typically declare separate source sets and separate `Test` tasks. See `samples/java/withIntegrationTests` in the full Gradle distribution for details.